# In R, how do I order within a single column so one category is ascending and one is descending?

Tags: r, sorting

I am generating multiple experimental designs of different sizes and shapes. This is done using a function dependent on the agricolae package (I’ve included it below). To generate practical data sheets for field operations I need to order the data frame by Row, then for odd Rows sort the Range ascending and for even Rows sort it descending.

Using sort, order, rep and seq I have been able to find a simple solution to this. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

So the data frame will go from something like this:

```
df1 <- structure(list(Block = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Range = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), Row = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L
), Plot = c(101L, 201L, 301L, 401L, 102L, 202L, 302L, 402L, 103L, 
203L, 303L, 403L, 104L, 204L, 304L, 404L, 105L, 205L, 305L, 405L, 
106L, 206L, 306L, 406L, 107L, 207L, 307L, 407L, 108L, 208L, 308L, 
408L, 109L, 209L, 309L, 409L, 110L, 210L, 310L, 410L, 111L, 211L, 
311L, 411L, 112L, 212L, 312L, 412L), Entry.Num = c(14L, 26L, 
18L, 4L, 52L, 17L, 41L, 47L, 40L, 30L, 21L, 12L, 9L, 2L, 8L, 
36L, 25L, 43L, 15L, 6L, 33L, 48L, 54L, 37L, 9L, 18L, 8L, 41L, 
48L, 28L, 7L, 47L, 54L, 38L, 46L, 23L, 19L, 1L, 3L, 27L, 36L, 
14L, 12L, 33L, 16L, 24L, 31L, 2L)), .Names = c("Block", "Range", 
"Row", "Plot", "Entry.Num"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-48L))
```

To something like this:

```
df2 <- structure(list(Block = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Range = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L), Row = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L
), Plot = c(101L, 201L, 301L, 401L, 402L, 302L, 202L, 102L, 103L, 
203L, 303L, 403L, 404L, 304L, 204L, 104L, 105L, 205L, 305L, 405L, 
406L, 306L, 206L, 106L, 107L, 207L, 307L, 407L, 408L, 308L, 208L, 
108L, 109L, 209L, 309L, 409L, 410L, 310L, 210L, 110L, 111L, 211L, 
311L, 411L, 412L, 312L, 212L, 112L), Entry.Num = c(14L, 26L, 
18L, 4L, 47L, 41L, 17L, 52L, 40L, 30L, 21L, 12L, 36L, 8L, 2L, 
9L, 25L, 43L, 15L, 6L, 37L, 54L, 48L, 33L, 9L, 18L, 8L, 41L, 
47L, 7L, 28L, 48L, 54L, 38L, 46L, 23L, 27L, 3L, 1L, 19L, 36L, 
14L, 12L, 33L, 2L, 31L, 24L, 16L)), .Names = c("Block", "Range", 
"Row", "Plot", "Entry.Num"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-48L))
```

In case you're interested, this is the trial design function. There is undoubtedly a more elegant way to do this but I am not particularly good at R:

```
Trial.Design <- function(Total.Entries, Rows.per.Block, Ranges.per.Block, Trial.Name){
  library(agricolae)
  library(reshape2)  
#########################################################################################
# Generate a trial design #
#########################################################################################

total.trt <- Total.Entries
if(total.trt%%2) # If the variety number is uneven it will return the following error message 
stop("WARNING: Variety number is uneven! Subsequent script will not work correctly!")

blocks <- 4 # This is fixed, we are unlikely to use a different block number in any trial.
trt<-c(1:total.trt) # You could in theory have the variety names here. 

# This function from agricolae generates a statistically sound trial design.
outdesign <-design.rcbd(trt, blocks, serie=0,continue=TRUE,986,"Wichmann-Hill") # seed for ranomization = 986

# This uses an agricolae function to print the "field book" of the trial. 
book <-outdesign$book # field book

#########################################################################################
# Generate blocking in two directions #
#########################################################################################
# The following generates an appropriately blocked map. The idea is block in two directions.
# We use this design so that the blocking structure captures field trends both down and across the field.
Block.Rows <- Rows.per.Block
Block.Ranges <- Ranges.per.Block
ifelse(total.trt==Block.Rows*Block.Ranges, "Entry number is okay", 
stop("WARNING: Block is uneven and/or does not equal entry number! Subsequent script will not work correctly!"))

Block <- matrix(rep(1, times=total.trt))
Range <- matrix(rep(1:Block.Rows, times=Block.Ranges))
Row <- matrix(rep(1:Block.Ranges, each=Block.Rows))
Block.1 <- cbind(Block, Range)
Block.1 <- cbind(Block.1, Row)

Block <- matrix(rep(3, times=total.trt))
Range <- matrix(rep((Block.Rows+1):(Block.Rows*2), times=Block.Ranges))
Row <- matrix(rep(1:Block.Ranges, each=Block.Rows))
Block.3 <- cbind(Block, Range)
Block.3 <- cbind(Block.3, Row)

Block <- matrix(rep(2, times=total.trt))
Range <- matrix(rep(1:Block.Rows, times=Block.Ranges))
Row <- matrix(rep((Block.Ranges+1):(Block.Ranges*2), each=Block.Rows))
Block.2 <- cbind(Block, Range)
Block.2 <- cbind(Block.2, Row)

Block <- matrix(rep(4, times=total.trt))
Range <- matrix(rep((Block.Rows+1):(Block.Rows*2), times=Block.Ranges))
Row <- matrix(rep((Block.Ranges+1):(Block.Ranges*2), each=Block.Rows))
Block.4 <- cbind(Block, Range)
Block.4 <- cbind(Block.4, Row)

# The following adds the coordinates generated above to our field book.
Field.book <- rbind(Block.1, Block.2)
Field.book <- rbind(Field.book, Block.3)
Field.book <- rbind(Field.book, Block.4)

Plots <- as.matrix(rep(1:(total.trt*4)))

Field.book <- cbind(Plots, Field.book)

# Generate temporary  Range names.
colnames(Field.book) <- c("plots", "block", "range", "row") 
Field.book <- as.data.frame(Field.book)

Field.book$range <- as.numeric(Field.book$range)
Field.book$row <- as.numeric(Field.book$row)

# This joins the experimental design generated by agricolae to the plot layout generated above.
Field.book <- join(Field.book, book, by= c("plots","block"))

# Generate better Range names.
colnames(Field.book) <- c("Plot.Num", "Block", "Range", "Row", "Entry.Num") 

# Create Plot coordinates.
Field.book$Plot <- (Field.book$Range * 100) + Field.book$Row

# Reorders the Ranges to something more intuitive.
# I drop the 'plot number' Range generated by agricolae because I don't think it is useful or necessary in our case.
Field.book <- Field.book[c("Block", "Range", "Row", "Plot",  "Entry.Num")]

# Sort the plots by Range and Row.
Field.book <- Field.book[order(Field.book$Range, Field.book$Row),] 
Field.book <<- Field.book

# Convert the Ranges to factors to allow for conversion to a 'wide' format.
Field.book$Block <- as.factor(Field.book$Block)
Field.book$Range <- as.factor(Field.book$Range)
Field.book$Row <- as.factor(Field.book$Row)
Field.book$Plot <- as.factor(Field.book$Plot)

#########################################################################################
# Generate plot maps #
#########################################################################################
# This function rotates the design if it's deemed necessary.
# rotate <- function(x) t(apply(x, 2, rev))

Field.design.num <- dcast(Field.book, Row ~ Range, value.var = "Entry.Num")
Field.design.num$Row <- as.numeric(Field.design.num$Row)
Field.design.num <- Field.design.num[order(-Field.design.num$Row),] 
Field.book$Plot <- as.factor(Field.book$Plot)
colnames(Field.design.num)[2:ncol(Field.design.num)] <- paste("Row", colnames(Field.design.num[,c(2:ncol(Field.design.num))]), sep = "-")
Field.design.num$Row <- sub("^", "Range-", Field.design.num$Row) 
#rotate(Field.design.num)
Field.design.num <<- Field.design.num

Field.design.plot <- dcast(Field.book, Row ~ Range, value.var = "Plot")
Field.design.plot$Row <- as.numeric(Field.design.plot$Row)
Field.design.plot <- Field.design.plot[order(-Field.design.plot$Row),] 
Field.book$Plot <- as.factor(Field.book$Plot)
colnames(Field.design.plot)[2:ncol(Field.design.plot)] <- paste("Row", colnames(Field.design.plot[,c(2:ncol(Field.design.plot))]), sep = "-")
Field.design.plot$Row <- sub("^", "Range-", Field.design.plot$Row) 
#rotate(Field.design.plot)
Field.design.plot <<- Field.design.plot

Field.design.Block <- dcast(Field.book, Row ~ Range, value.var = "Block")
Field.design.Block$Row <- as.numeric(Field.design.Block$Row)
Field.design.Block <- Field.design.Block[order(-Field.design.Block$Row),] 
Field.book$Block <- as.factor(Field.book$Block)
colnames(Field.design.Block)[2:ncol(Field.design.Block)] <- paste("Row", colnames(Field.design.Block[,c(2:ncol(Field.design.Block))]), sep = "-")
Field.design.Block$Row <- sub("^", "Range-", Field.design.Block$Row) 
#rotate(Field.design.Block)
Field.design.Block <<- Field.design.Block

#########################################################################################
# Write the files #
#########################################################################################
write.csv(Field.book,  paste("Field Book",Trial.Name,".csv"), row.names=FALSE)
write.csv(Field.design.num, paste("Field map Entry",Trial.Name,".csv"), row.names=FALSE)
write.csv(Field.design.plot, paste("Field map Plots",Trial.Name,".csv"), row.names=FALSE)
write.csv(Field.design.Block, paste("Field map Blocks",Trial.Name,".csv"), row.names=FALSE)
#########################################################################################

}


# The parameters are:
    # The total number of entires/varieties in a replicate (NOTE: The number of entries must be an even number).
    # The number of rows in an individual block/replicate.
    # The number of ranges in an individual block/replicate.
    # (NOTE: The number of rows and ranges must multiply to give the number of entries.)
# The trial name is what will be written to your working directory.

Total.Entries = 54
Rows.per.Block = 9
Ranges.per.Block = 6
Trial.Name = "Example"

Trial.Design (Total.Entries, Rows.per.Block, Ranges.per.Block, Trial.Name)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The magic of `order` awaits you:

```
df1[order(df1$Row, c(-1,1)[df1$Row %% 2 + 1] * df1$Range ),]
```

Essentially what this does is order by `Row`, then by `Range`, multiplied by `-1` if it is even. `x %% 2` can be used to check for odd/even status.

```
all.equal(
  df1[order(df1$Row, c(-1,1)[df1$Row %% 2 + 1] * df1$Range ),],
  df2,
  check.attributes=FALSE
)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: It's always something simple. Thanks.